# PHP: fill array from resultset

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, resultset

The code shown below is used to manually fill an array.

```
    <?php
        include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';   
        $data = array(
            array(0,array("111",' EE112',' AA','FT445'),"2004-03-01 10:00","2004-03-01 14:00"),
            array(1,array("111",' BC124',' RYA','FE675'),"2004-03-01 16:00","2004-03-01 18:00"),
            array(2,array("11",' BE225',' FA','AE667'),"2004-03-01 09:00","2004-03-01 10:00"),
            array(3,array("11",' TC828',' BA','FF745'),"2004-03-01 06:00","2004-03-01 08:00")
        );
?>
```

Now I want to fill this array from the database:

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM MyData;";
$result1=DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query1);

 <?php foreach ($result1 as $row):?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['resReg']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['resTitle']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['resAvailability'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
```

How to assign the columns of result1 to the columns of the array?

Comment: How can anyone answer without *any clue at all* regarding what `$result1` is?

Comment: Please look at the updated code, although an example based on another data would also be helpful.

Comment: That's still painfully inadequate. Which fields does the query fetch? What is their relation to the "manual" array fields? Speaking of which, column 1 in the manual case contains arrays. What arrays are these? What are their contents? How do they map to what the query returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am i right assuming you want to do something like this:

```
<?php

$query1  = "SELECT name,color1,color2 FROM MyPets;";
$result1 = DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQueryArray($query1);
$petArray = array();

foreach($result1 as $pet):
  $petArray[] = array('name' => $pet['name'],
                      'colors' => array(
                           $pet['color1'],
                           $pet['color2'])
                     );
?>
```